# Message not going frm ngrok to Rasa in Slack integration

Tags: chatbot, slack, slack-api, ngrok, rasa

Facing problem in Slack integration with Rasa 1.* command line way.

Steps followed are:

- Created a workspace (“DataHacksConf2019”), a channel ("#rasachatbot") and an app (“rasachatbotdemo”).
- Noted down Bot user OAuth (starting with xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
- Turned Event subscription ON. Subscribe to workspace events: message.channel , message.groups , message.im and message.mpim
- Re-installed the app
- Changed credentials.yml file with the Slack chat bot OAuth token (starting with xoxb)
- So, my credentials.yml has only following two lines:

```
    slack:
      slack_token: "xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

- Ngrok is started on port 5002 to the internet:

```
    C:\Temp\ngrok.exe http 5002
```

- Noted down different ngrok token, 375d7c95, used that below
- So, my endpoints.yml has only following two lines

```
        action_endpoint:
         url: "http://375d7c95.ngrok.io:5002/webhook"
```

Is above setting correct or should it be as below?

```
        action_endpoint:
         url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

- Ran rasa action server by

```
python -W ignore -m rasa run actions
```

- So, my action server was running at 5055
- In another window, with activated rasa environment on a different port 5002, same port as ngrok, started rasa server

```
    python -W ignore -m rasa run --connector slack --port 5002 --cors *
```

- Started chatting in Slack

The message seems to go from Slack to ngrok on 5002 (says status ok 200), but from there its not showing up in rasa server running on 5002

Am I missing anything?

All necessary files are at https://github.com/yogeshhk/TeachingDataScience/tree/master/Jupyter/iplbot/cli_version

Answer (score 0):

endpoints.yml should look like:

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Because action_endpoint is for the actions, not for anything else, and it can run on default port 5055.

Slack -> ngrok -> Rasa server is the main message flow path. So, between rasa server and ngrok the port has to be same, say 5004. Then between ngrok and slack the url token has to be same. This how chaining/binding is done.

Another observation: Need to start rasa server on , say 5004, first, then ngrok http on 5004, then get the ngrok url token, put it in Slack Verify then only it verifies fine else it errors. Order seems important